# C#: Including assemblies without visual studio

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

How do I include an external assembly .dll in a C# .exe? I'm specifically working with the MySql connectors for .NET 4.0.

Please note, I'm not using Visual Studio at this time and do not plan to in order to accomplish this. Here's the error I get when I compile: CS0246: The type or namespace MySql could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have tried:
- Copying the .dlls into the source folder for the project.
- Copying the .dlls into the .NET folder under Windows

The first three lines of code are:

```
using System;
using MySql;
using MySql.Data;
```

Comment: References are also added in the project and solution files which are a pain to edit. It's possible but you are way better off using VS

Comment: Just in case you can't use VS, just try SharpDevelop ( [link](http://www.icsharpcode.net/) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample Program  (Program.cs)

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace TestApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string [] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
            var command = new MySqlCommand();
            Console.WriteLine(command.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Project file (TestApp.csproj)

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="Build">
    <Csc Sources="@(Compile)" AdditionalLibPaths="lib" References="MySql.Data.dll">
    </Csc>
</Target>
</Project>
```

MySql.Data.dll is in a folder named lib 
Run msbuild from the command line

```
msbuild TestApp.csproj /t:Build
```

Microsoft's guide to writing your own msbuild files.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576348.aspx

csc task details
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5c8athz.aspx

Comment: Thank you Darryl. After posting the question I started working with the MSBuild instead of just csc. Your note on the additional libraries and references helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the /reference (or /r) command line option:

```
csc yourcode.cs /r:MySql.Data.dll
```

Assuming that, as you said, you have copied the MySql.Data.dll into the source folder for the project.

If you haven't copied the dynamic link libray to your source folder, then you can use the /lib: command line option to specify additional directories to search in for your references.